# Challenging almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ a sequence of iif uniform variables on $]0,1[$.
I managed to find the distribution of $Y_n=\prod_{i=1}^n{X_i}$ but I now need to show that it converges almost surely towards $0$.
I can't really get this result though.

Comment: What happens if many of the $X_i$ are less than $1/2$?

Comment: I assume "iif" is a typo and is supposed to be "iid."

Answer (score 2):

Use the Strong Law of Large Numbers to examine $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(Y_n)$. Before you start the examination, compute $\Bbb E[\log(X_1)]$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$ converges to $0$ if and only if for any $N$, there exists a $n_0$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i \leq \frac{1}{N}$ for any $n \geq n_0$.

Now, let us fix an $N$. We have
$$ P\left(\bigcap_n  \left\{\prod_{i=1}^n X_i > \frac{1}{N}\right\} \right) \leq P\left(\bigcap_i \left\{X_i > \frac{1}{N}\right\}\right)\leq P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n'} \left\{X_i > \frac{1}{N}\right\}\right)= \left(\frac{N-1}{N} \right)^{n'}$$
where it holds for any $n'$. In particular, making $n'$ tend to $+\infty$ gives $P\left(\bigcap_n \left\{  \prod_{i=1}^n X_i > \frac{1}{N} \right\}\right) = 0$.

In the end, we have that
$$\begin{align*} P((X_n) \text{ does not tend to }0) &= P\left(\bigcup_N \bigcap_n  \left\{\prod_{i=1}^n X_i > \frac{1}{N}\right\}\right) \\ &\leq \sum_N P\left(\bigcap_n\left\{  \prod_{i=1}^n X_i > \frac{1}{N}\right\}\right) \\ &= 0. \end{align*}$$

Comment: I touched up  the formatting.  For the future, it's best to use `\prod` for infinite products instead of `\Pi`, and use `\bigcup, \bigcap` for unions of sequences or indexed families.

Comment: Hey, ok thanks for the tip, and thanks a lot for the formatting. It looks way better !

Answer (score 0):

Following Michael's hint, use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma (the one about independent events) to show that with probability 1, we have $X_i \le 1/2$ for infinitely many $i$.  On this event, the product converges to 0.  Indeed, since $X_i \le 1$ for all $i$, if at least $n$ of the $X_i$ are less than $1/2$, then the product is less than $1/2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to do this. If you don't want to apply Borel-Cantelli and the fact that if for a sequence of rvs $X_{n}$, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{n}|>\epsilon)<\infty$ then $X_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$, then you can do the follwing

Start with finding the probability that $P(|Y_{n}|>\epsilon)=P(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}>\epsilon)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}P(X_{i}>\epsilon)$

This is simply because if one $X_{i_{0}}\leq \epsilon$, then the product will have to be less than $\epsilon$ as you are multiplying numbers which are less than equal to $1$.

But $\prod_{i=1}^{n}P(X_{i}>\epsilon)=(1-\epsilon)^{n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ (and is also summable). Thus $Y_{n}\xrightarrow{P} 0$ (i,e. we have convergence in probability)

Now, you can pass to a subsequence $Y_{n_{k}}$ such that you have $Y_{n_{k}}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$ by using the result that if a sequence $Z_{n}$ converges in probability to $0$ , then there exists a subsequence $Z_{n_{k}}$ such that $Z_{n_{k}}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$.

But a convergence for the subsequence in this case is already enough for convergence almost surely for the whole sequence $Y_{n}$ , as because $Y_{n}$ is monotone decreasing.